# Valid range in Rails time_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is there a way to apply a range to the time_select helper?

I am trying to set it to valid working hours, something like:

```
time_select('object_name', 'method', { :start_hour => 09, :end_hour => 17, :minute_step => 05 })
```

How should I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that.
You have to change the select_hour method on DateTimeSelector, like this :

```
module ActionView
  module Helpers
    class DateTimeSelector
      def select_hour
        if @options[:use_hidden] || @options[:discard_hour]
          build_hidden(:hour, hour)
        else
          build_options_and_select(:hour, hour, :start => @options[:start_hour], :end => @options[:end_hour], :ampm => @options[:ampm])
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

(not tested)

Comment: Hi, Thomas. Thank you for the answer. It is somewhat disappointing, though, that I would have to change Rails internals to achieve something I would expect to be so simple. I mean, setting a 'time range' to a 'time selector' doesn't sound like asking for much, does it? If you do not mind, I'll wait until tomorrow to see if anyone has a different take on the matter. If not, I'll set your answer as the accepted one. Once again, thanks.